# How to scale objects around a point, mantaining an anchor point fixed on illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, scale

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGAdzGj4vR0

There are multiple copies of a losange, rotated around the base anchor of the center one.

The guy on the video just rotate and copy the pieces with the rotate tool, and then scale each one with move tool. But when I try to do that, holding shift or alt, not holding any key, the piece move away from the center.

Even using the scale tool, where we can choose the reference point, it doesn't scale properly, it's like the shift is constantly pressed.

I need to scale freely but with the anchor point fixed. What can I do?

Comment: I came here because I was trying to choose an anchor or reference point while scaling my object in illustrator, select object -> press S -> click where you wish the anchor -> click on the object and drag (with SHIFT for maintaining the aspect ratio)

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't use the scale tool to re-size the shapes.  He just switches to the select tool and the grabs a handle on the control box on the side he wants to move and the opposite end stays anchored.

**Step by step:**

1. Create your shape.
2. Switch to the rotate tool.
3. Click where you want to set the focus of the rotate.
4. Click drag to rotate, then press option to duplicate the shape then
   release the mouse button.
5. Click the select tool (solid arrow) the shape should now have
   handles (hollow boxes) in the middle of each side of it's bounding
   box.
6. Click drag the control point on the side opposite of the rotate
   focus point.